# PHP MSSQL Query Error for Pagination

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, pagination

I have been trying to get a pagination query to work for MSSQL.   I have tested the connection and if I just run a select all it runs fine.  So there is no connection issues.

```
 $result = mssql_query("SELECT * FROM DriverAppInfo ORDER BY appdate")
```

The following is my code.  I am looking to return the first 20 records then be able to increment $startrow and have the next page show these results.  I have been able to get this to work for MYSQL but the conversion to MSSQL and not having a LIMIT function is throwing me for a loop.

```
if (!isset($_GET['startrow']) or !is_numeric($_GET['startrow'])) {
$startrow = 0;
} else {
  $startrow = (int)$_GET['startrow'];
}



 $result = mssql_query("SELECT TOP 20 FROM DriverAppInfo WHERE appdate NOT IN 
                     (SELECT TOP $startrow FROM DriverAppInfo ORDER BY appdate ASC )
              ORDER BY appdate ASC") 

                or die("Couldn't connect to SQL Server Table on $myDB");
```

It then errors out on connection to the table. So something is wrong with my query syntax.  Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: `select top 0` doesn't make much sense...

Comment: @Marc B select top 0 should select nothing then you would get the first 20 records as your first page.  The next page $startrow would get incremented by 20 and you would have SELECT TOP 20 not in the selected 20. So you would get records 21-40

Answer (score 2):

In SQL Server, `row_number()` provides an easy way to paginate:

```
select  *
from    (
        select  row_number() over (order by appdate) rn
        ,       *
        from    DriverAppInfo
        ) as SubQueryAlias
where   rn between 21 and 40 -- Second page
```

If you have SQL Server 2012, you can use `offset`:

```
select  *
from    DriverAppInfo
order by
        appdate
offset 20 rows
fetch next 20 rows only
```